# onclick button not working in react - seprate js file not run

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I wrote the Code and it has a separate script file, but when I click on the button `next` or `before`, the `nextPrev` does not work , I have put all the JS codes into the `useEffect` and I don't know if this method is correct or not

show error:

```
  Line 174:57:  'nextPrev' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 175:57:  'nextPrev' is not defined  no-undef
```

```
const AddTest = () => {

  useEffect(()=>{
    var currentTab = 0; // Current tab is set to be the first tab (0)
    showTab(currentTab); // Display the current tab
    
    function showTab(n) {
      // This function will display the specified tab of the form...
      var x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
      x[n].style.display = "block";
      //... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
      if (n == 0) {
        document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
      }
      if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
        document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
      }
      //... and run a function that will display the correct step indicator:
      fixStepIndicator(n)
    }
    
    const nextPrev = (n) => {
      // This function will figure out which tab to display
      var x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
      // Exit the function if any field in the current tab is invalid:
      if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false;
      // Hide the current tab:
      x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
      // Increase or decrease the current tab by 1:
      currentTab = currentTab + n;
      // if you have reached the end of the form...
      if (currentTab >= x.length) {
        // ... the form gets submitted:
        document.getElementById("signUpForm").submit();
        return false;
      }
      // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
      showTab(currentTab);
    }
    
    function validateForm() {
      // This function deals with validation of the form fields
      var x, y, i, valid = true;
      x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
      y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
      // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
      for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
        // If a field is empty...
        if (y[i].value == "") {
          // add an "invalid" class to the field:
          y[i].className += " invalid";
          // and set the current valid status to false
          valid = false;
        }
      }
      // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
      if (valid) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("stepIndicator")[currentTab].className += " finish";
      }
      return valid; // return the valid status
    }
    
    function fixStepIndicator(n) {
      // This function removes the "active" class of all steps...
      var i, x = document.getElementsByClassName("stepIndicator");
      for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", "");
      }
      //... and adds the "active" class on the current step:
      x[n].className += " active";
    }
  })
    return (
        <>
        <div className="row">
          <p>njjj</p>
        <form id="signUpForm" className="md-12" action="#!">
        <div className="form-header d-flex mb-4">
            <span className="stepIndicator">Setting</span>
            <span className="stepIndicator">Question</span>
            <span className="stepIndicator">Des</span>
            <span className="stepIndicator">View</span>
        </div>

        <div className="step">
            <p className="text-center mb-4">Create your account</p>
            <div className="form-row">
                <div className="col-md-6 mb-3">
                  <input type="text" className="form-control" id="validationCustom01" placeholder="First name" required />
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-6 mb-3">
                  <input type="text" className="form-control" id="validationCustom02" placeholder="Last name" required />
                </div>
              </div>

              <div className="form-row">
                <div className="col-md-12 mb-3">
                  <textarea className="form-control"></textarea>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div className="form-row">
                <div className="col-md-12 mb-3">
                  <input type="text" className="form-control" id="validationCustom01" placeholder="First name" required />
                </div>
              </div>

              <div className="form-group">
                <label for="company_name" className="font-weight-bold text-right">Sport</label>

                <div className="form-row">
                  <div className="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                    <input type="radio" id="customRadioInline1" name="customRadioInline1" className="custom-control-input" />
                    <label className="custom-control-label" for="customRadioInline1">5 </label>
                  </div>
                  <div className="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                    <input type="radio" id="customRadioInline2" name="customRadioInline1" className="custom-control-input" />
                    <label className="custom-control-label" for="customRadioInline2">10 </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

        </div>

        <div className="step">
            <p className="text-center mb-4">Create your account</p>
            <div className="mb-3">
                <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" oninput="this.className = ''" name="email" />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" oninput="this.className = ''" name="password" />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
                <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" oninput="this.className = ''" name="password" />
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <div className="step">
            <p className="text-center mb-4">Your presence on the social network</p>
            <div className="mb-3">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Linked In" oninput="this.className = ''" name="linkedin" />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Twitter" oninput="this.className = ''" name="twitter" />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Facebook" oninput="this.className = ''" name="facebook" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div className="step">
            <p className="text-center mb-4">We will never sell it</p>
            <div className="mb-3">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Full name" oninput="this.className = ''" name="fullname" />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Mobile" oninput="this.className = ''" name="mobile" />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Address" oninput="this.className = ''" name="address" />
            </div>
        </div>

        
        <div className="form-footer d-flex">
            <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onClick={nextPrev(-1)}>Before</button>
            <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onClick={nextPrev(1)}>Next</button>
        </div>
    </form>

        </div>
      </> 
    );
  };
  
  export default AddTest;
```

Answer (score 0):

Type error.

Change this:

```
<div className="form-footer d-flex">
    <button type="button" id="prevBtn" nClick={nextPrev(-1)}>Before</button>
    <button type="button" id="nextBtn" nClick={nextPrev(1)}>Next</button>
</div>
```

to:

```
<div className="form-footer d-flex">
    <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onClick={nextPrev(-1)}>Before</button>
    <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onClick={nextPrev(1)}>Next</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put your `methods` on the `useEffect` hook, it will be scoped inside and you can't call it in the `DOM`, you need to keep it outside, and turn the `currentTab` to a state and set it as a dependency to the `useEffect`

```
const AddTest = () => {
    const [currentTab, setCurrentTab] = useState(0)
    function showTab(n) {
        // This function will display the specified tab of the form...
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
        x[n].style.display = "block";
        //... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
        if (n == 0) {
          document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
        } else {
          document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
        }
        if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
          document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
        } else {
          document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
        }
        //... and run a function that will display the correct step indicator:
        fixStepIndicator(n)
      }
    
    const nextPrev = (n) => {
        // This function will figure out which tab to display
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
        // Exit the function if any field in the current tab is invalid:
        if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false;
        // Hide the current tab:
        x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
        // Increase or decrease the current tab by 1:
        setCurrentTab(prev => prev + n)
        // if you have reached the end of the form...
        if (currentTab >= x.length) {
          // ... the form gets submitted:
          document.getElementById("signUpForm").submit();
          return false;
        }
        // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
        showTab(currentTab);
      }

      function validateForm() {
        // This function deals with validation of the form fields
        var x, y, i, valid = true;
        x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
        y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
        // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
        for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
          // If a field is empty...
          if (y[i].value == "") {
            // add an "invalid" class to the field:
            y[i].className += " invalid";
            // and set the current valid status to false
            valid = false;
          }
        }
        // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
        if (valid) {
          document.getElementsByClassName("stepIndicator")[currentTab].className += " finish";
        }
        return valid; // return the valid status
      }
      
      function fixStepIndicator(n) {
        // This function removes the "active" class of all steps...
        var i, x = document.getElementsByClassName("stepIndicator");
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
          x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        //... and adds the "active" class on the current step:
        x[n].className += " active";
      }
  useEffect(()=>{
    showTab(currentTab); // Display the current tab
  }, [currentTab])
    return (
        <>
        <div className="row">
          <p>njjj</p>
        <form id="signUpForm" className="md-12" action="#!">
        <div className="form-header d-flex mb-4">
            <span className="stepIndicator">Setting</span>
            <span className="stepIndicator">Question</span>
            <span className="stepIndicator">Des</span>
            <span className="stepIndicator">View</span>
        </div>

        <div className="step">
            <p className="text-center mb-4">Create your account</p>
            <div className="form-row">
                <div className="col-md-6 mb-3">
                  <input type="text" className="form-control" id="validationCustom01" placeholder="First name" required />
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-6 mb-3">
                  <input type="text" className="form-control" id="validationCustom02" placeholder="Last name" required />
                </div>
              </div>

              <div className="form-row">
                <div className="col-md-12 mb-3">
                  <textarea className="form-control"></textarea>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div className="form-row">
                <div className="col-md-12 mb-3">
                  <input type="text" className="form-control" id="validationCustom01" placeholder="First name" required />
                </div>
              </div>

              <div className="form-group">
                <label for="company_name" className="font-weight-bold text-right">Sport</label>

                <div className="form-row">
                  <div className="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                    <input type="radio" id="customRadioInline1" name="customRadioInline1" className="custom-control-input" />
                    <label className="custom-control-label" for="customRadioInline1">5 </label>
                  </div>
                  <div className="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                    <input type="radio" id="customRadioInline2" name="customRadioInline1" className="custom-control-input" />
                    <label className="custom-control-label" for="customRadioInline2">10 </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

        </div>

        <div className="step">
            <p className="text-center mb-4">Create your account</p>
            <div className="mb-3">
                <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" oninput="this.className = ''" name="email" />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" oninput="this.className = ''" name="password" />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
                <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" oninput="this.className = ''" name="password" />
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <div className="step">
            <p className="text-center mb-4">Your presence on the social network</p>
            <div className="mb-3">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Linked In" oninput="this.className = ''" name="linkedin" />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Twitter" oninput="this.className = ''" name="twitter" />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Facebook" oninput="this.className = ''" name="facebook" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div className="step">
            <p className="text-center mb-4">We will never sell it</p>
            <div className="mb-3">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Full name" oninput="this.className = ''" name="fullname" />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Mobile" oninput="this.className = ''" name="mobile" />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Address" oninput="this.className = ''" name="address" />
            </div>
        </div>

        
        <div className="form-footer d-flex">
            <button type="button" id="prevBtn" nClick={nextPrev(-1)}>Before</button>
            <button type="button" id="nextBtn" nClick={nextPrev(1)}>Next</button>
        </div>
    </form>

        </div>
      </> 
    );
  };
  
  export default AddTest;
```

Comment: i have a error `Uncaught TypeError: x[currentTab] is undefined
    nextPrev AddTest.js:33
    AddTest AddTest.js:173`

Answer (score 0):

you do have a few mistakes in the syntax

for example:

```html
        <div className="mb-3">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Full name" oninput="this.className = ''" name="fullname" />
        </div>
```

`oninput` in react should be `onInput`

also the buttons do not have an active onclick functions.

you missed the `o` in `onClick` on the buttons and you're actively calling the function.

here's how they should be:

```
    <div className="form-footer d-flex">
        <button type="button" id="prevBtn" nClick={()=>nextPrev(-1)}>Before</button>
        <button type="button" id="nextBtn" nClick={()=>nextPrev(1)}>Next</button>
    </div>
```

Also you're calling the function in useEffect which is why it's not reading it. move it outside of the useEffect

here is the full code fix:

```
    const AddTest = () => {
        const nextPrev = (n) => {
          // This function will figure out which tab to display
          var x = document.getElementsByClassName('step')
          // Exit the function if any field in the current tab is invalid:
          if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false
          // Hide the current tab:
          x[currentTab].style.display = 'none'
          // Increase or decrease the current tab by 1:
          currentTab = currentTab + n
          // if you have reached the end of the form...
          if (currentTab >= x.length) {
            // ... the form gets submitted:
            document.getElementById('signUpForm').submit()
            return false
          }
          // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
          showTab(currentTab)
        }
      useEffect(()=>{
        var currentTab = 0; // Current tab is set to be the first tab (0)
        showTab(currentTab); // Display the current tab
        
        function showTab(n) {
          // This function will display the specified tab of the form...
          var x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
          x[n].style.display = "block";
          //... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
          if (n == 0) {
            document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
          } else {
            document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
          }
          if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
            document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
          } else {
            document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
          }
          //... and run a function that will display the correct step indicator:
          fixStepIndicator(n)
        }
        
    
        
        function validateForm() {
          // This function deals with validation of the form fields
          var x, y, i, valid = true;
          x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
          y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
          // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
          for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
            // If a field is empty...
            if (y[i].value == "") {
              // add an "invalid" class to the field:
              y[i].className += " invalid";
              // and set the current valid status to false
              valid = false;
            }
          }
          // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
          if (valid) {
            document.getElementsByClassName("stepIndicator")[currentTab].className += " finish";
          }
          return valid; // return the valid status
        }
        
        function fixStepIndicator(n) {
          // This function removes the "active" class of all steps...
          var i, x = document.getElementsByClassName("stepIndicator");
          for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", "");
          }
          //... and adds the "active" class on the current step:
          x[n].className += " active";
        }
      })
        return (
            <>
            <div className="row">
              <p>njjj</p>
            <form id="signUpForm" className="md-12" action="#!">
            <div className="form-header d-flex mb-4">
                <span className="stepIndicator">Setting</span>
                <span className="stepIndicator">Question</span>
                <span className="stepIndicator">Des</span>
                <span className="stepIndicator">View</span>
            </div>
    
            <div className="step">
                <p className="text-center mb-4">Create your account</p>
                <div className="form-row">
                    <div className="col-md-6 mb-3">
                      <input type="text" className="form-control" id="validationCustom01" placeholder="First name" required />
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-6 mb-3">
                      <input type="text" className="form-control" id="validationCustom02" placeholder="Last name" required />
                    </div>
                  </div>
    
                  <div className="form-row">
                    <div className="col-md-12 mb-3">
                      <textarea className="form-control"></textarea>
                    </div>
                  </div>
    
                  <div className="form-row">
                    <div className="col-md-12 mb-3">
                      <input type="text" className="form-control" id="validationCustom01" placeholder="First name" required />
                    </div>
                  </div>
    
                  <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="company_name" className="font-weight-bold text-right">Sport</label>
    
                    <div className="form-row">
                      <div className="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                        <input type="radio" id="customRadioInline1" name="customRadioInline1" className="custom-control-input" />
                        <label className="custom-control-label" htmlFor="customRadioInline1">5 </label>
                      </div>
                      <div className="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                        <input type="radio" id="customRadioInline2" name="customRadioInline1" className="custom-control-input" />
                        <label className="custom-control-label" htmlFor="customRadioInline2">10 </label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
    
            </div>
    
            <div className="step">
                <p className="text-center mb-4">Create your account</p>
                <div className="mb-3">
                    <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" onInput="this.className = ''" name="email" />
                </div>
                <div className="mb-3">
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" onInput="this.className = ''" name="password" />
                </div>
                <div className="mb-3">
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" onInput="this.className = ''" name="password" />
                </div>
            </div>
        
            <div className="step">
                <p className="text-center mb-4">Your presence on the social network</p>
                <div className="mb-3">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Linked In" onInput="this.className = ''" name="linkedin" />
                </div>
                <div className="mb-3">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Twitter" onInput="this.className = ''" name="twitter" />
                </div>
                <div className="mb-3">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Facebook" onInput="this.className = ''" name="facebook" />
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <div className="step">
                <p className="text-center mb-4">We will never sell it</p>
                <div className="mb-3">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Full name" onInput="this.className = ''" name="fullname" />
                </div>
                <div className="mb-3">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Mobile" onInput="this.className = ''" name="mobile" />
                </div>
                <div className="mb-3">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Address" onInput="this.className = ''" name="address" />
                </div>
            </div>
    
            
            <div className="form-footer d-flex">
                <button type="button" id="prevBtn" nClick={nextPrev(-1)}>Before</button>
                <button type="button" id="nextBtn" nClick={nextPrev(1)}>Next</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    
            </div>
          </> 
        );
      };
      
      export default AddTest;
```

Comment: not true i have more error:

```Line 11:20:  'validateForm' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 13:7:   'currentTab' is not defined    no-undef
  Line 15:5:   'currentTab' is not defined    no-undef
  Line 15:18:  'currentTab' is not defined    no-undef
  Line 17:9:   'currentTab' is not defined    no-undef
  Line 23:5:   'showTab' is not defined       no-undef
  Line 23:13:  'currentTab' is not defined    no-undef```

Comment: gotta move the functions out of the useEffect in order for them to be readable by the whole code.
That would be solving part of the problem. i think @mina's answer above referenced most of this

Comment: that's not working